# Continued content slider in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm looking for a content slider in jQuery. That plugin http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/building-a-jquery-image-scroller/ is the most similar to this that I want. The change is, I don't want to see an empty space in the container when the last item hides on the left, I want that animation to be played continued. In the other words, I want to be the first item to be joined with the last item.

Does anyone know a plugin with that functionality ?

Answer (score 2):

You could use [slideJS](http://slidesjs.com/) and enable its `autoplay` feature like in this example taken from their site:

```
 $("#slides").slides({
     play: 5000
 });
```

Comment: almost perfect, but every item stops when it is filled in the container. I've tested play: 1000

Comment: Played a bit with the options, you could set `play:1`, `start:1` and `slideSpeed:2000` for a continous look.